# Why can't NULL be a function pointer template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

When I try to compile this in GCC or clang, I get an error.

```cpp
#include <cstddef>

template <void (*Function)()>
void Wrapper()
{
}

int main()
{
    void (*meow)() = Wrapper<NULL>;
    return meow ? 1 : 0;
}
```

```
$ g++ -m64 -std=c++11 -c nulltemplate.cpp
nulltemplate.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
nulltemplate.cpp:10:19: error: no matches converting function ‘Wrapper’ to type ‘void (*)()’
nulltemplate.cpp:4:6: error: candidate is: template<void (* Function)()> void Wrapper()
```

Why can't I do this?  The error's wording is as if `Wrapper` were an overload that can't be contextually resolved to a particular function pointer type, which doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Use `nullptr` instead. `NULL` on your implementation isn't of pointer type.

Answer (score 7):

`NULL` is a macro which may be defined as (and does seem to be, on your system):

```
#define NULL 0
```

It has type `int`. So your code is doing `Wrapper<0>`

However, for a non-type template parameter which is a function pointer, you have to pass either an actual function designator, or a *null pointer value*.  The implicit conversion from integer-to-pointer is not considered.  `0` is a *null pointer constant*, but not a *null pointer value*.

C++11 introduced `nullptr` to avoid just this sort of issue; `nullptr` cannot be confused with integers.

The full list of conditions for non-type template arguments, and the list of which conversions are considered, can be found in section [temp.arg.nontype] of the C++ Standard.

Comment: That's not required to be `NULL`'s definition, and it isn't on Clang or GCC.